# Why does every Char static "Is..." have a string overload, e.g. IsWhiteSpace(string, Int32)?

Tags: c#

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x308yk8.aspx

This allows me to do this:

```
var str = "string ";
Char.IsWhiteSpace(str, 6);
```

Rather than:

```
Char.IsWhiteSpace(str[6]);
```

Seems unusual, so I looked at the reflection:

```
[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
public static bool IsWhiteSpace(char c)
{
    if (char.IsLatin1(c))
    {
        return char.IsWhiteSpaceLatin1(c);
    }
    return CharUnicodeInfo.IsWhiteSpace(c);
}

[SecuritySafeCritical]
public static bool IsWhiteSpace(string s, int index)
{
    if (s == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
    }
    if (index >= s.Length)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
    }
    if (char.IsLatin1(s[index]))
    {
        return char.IsWhiteSpaceLatin1(s[index]);
    }
    return CharUnicodeInfo.IsWhiteSpace(s, index);
}
```

Three things struck me:

1. Why does it bother to do the limit check only on the upper bound? Throwing an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, while index below 0 would give string's standard `IndexOutOfRangeException`
2. The precense of [`SecuritySafeCriticalAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securitysafecriticalattribute(v=vs.95).aspx) which I've read the general blerb about, but still unclear what it is doing here and if it is linked to the upper bound check.
3. `TargetedPatchingOptOutAttribute` is not present on other `Is...(char)` methods. Example `IsLetter`, `IsNumber` etc.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because not every character fits in a `C#` char. For instance, `""` takes 2 C# `chars`, and you couldn't get any information about that character with just a `char` overload. With `String` and an index, the methods can see if the character at index `i` is a High Surrogate `char`, and then read the Low Surrogate `char` at next index, [add them up according to the algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF), and retrieve info about the code point [`U+20000`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20000/index.htm).

This is how UTF-16 can encode 1 million different code points, it's a variable-width encoding. It takes 2-4 bytes to encode a character, or 1-2 C# chars.

Answer (score 4):

> Why does it bother to do the limit check only on the upper bound?

It doesn't. It performs an *unsigned* comparison, so every negative number will compare larger than the length and cause the appropriate exception to be thrown. This happens to not get decompiled accurately.

Comment: Ah, nice catch, thanks. People should upvote this, it checks out! `IL_0015: blt.un.s IL_0022`